# Css border animation text overflow issue in mobile

Tags: html, css

I'm creating heading border animation effect that expand left and bottom border whenever header element came into viewport.

```js
(function () {
    var elements;
    var windowHeight;

    function init() {
        elements = document.querySelectorAll(".custom-heading");
        windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    }

    function checkPosition() {
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            var element = elements[i];
            var positionFromTop = elements[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;

            if (positionFromTop - windowHeight <= 0) {
                element.classList.add("ch-animate");
            }
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener("scroll", checkPosition);
    window.addEventListener("resize", init);

    init();
    checkPosition();
})();
```

```css
.custom-heading {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100% !important;
}

.custom-heading .text {
    line-height: 1.5em;
    padding-left: 2rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
    max-height: 2em;
}

.bh-line,
.vl-line {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background-color: #d70522;
    transition: all 3s ease;
}

.bh-line {
    left: 0;
    bottom: 15%;
    height: 3px;
    width: 0%;
}

.vl-line {
    left: 1rem;
    bottom: -0.3rem;
    height: 0;
    width: 3px;
}

.custom-heading.ch-animate .bh-line {
    width: 100%;
}

.custom-heading.ch-animate .vl-line {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-heading">
    <span class="vl-line"></span>
    <h1 class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h1>
    <span class="bh-line"></span>
</div>
```

but in mobile view or small screen text overflow's the bottom border, is there any way I can fit the text top of bottom line and right to left line. see the pictures

Problem:

[text overflow issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dz2l.png)

Expected behavior:

[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYgNa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `display: inline-table` to `.custom-heading .text`. Like that:

```
.custom-heading .text {
    ...
    display: inline-table;
}
```

After this edit, the indents between the text and lines will be **uniform**.

```js
(function () {
    var elements;
    var windowHeight;

    function init() {
        elements = document.querySelectorAll(".custom-heading");
        windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    }

    function checkPosition() {
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            var element = elements[i];
            var positionFromTop = elements[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;

            if (positionFromTop - windowHeight <= 0) {
                element.classList.add("ch-animate");
            }
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener("scroll", checkPosition);
    window.addEventListener("resize", init);

    init();
    checkPosition();
})();
```

```css
.custom-heading {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100% !important;
}

.custom-heading .text {
    line-height: 1.5em;
    padding-left: 2rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
    max-height: 2em;
    display: inline-table;
}

.bh-line,
.vl-line {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background-color: #d70522;
    transition: all 3s ease;
}

.bh-line {
    left: 0;
    bottom: 15%;
    height: 3px;
    width: 0%;
}

.vl-line {
    left: 1rem;
    bottom: -0.3rem;
    height: 0;
    width: 3px;
}

.custom-heading.ch-animate .bh-line {
    width: 100%;
}

.custom-heading.ch-animate .vl-line {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-heading">
    <span class="vl-line"></span>
    <h1 class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h1>
    <span class="bh-line"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue comes from your `max-height: 2em;` on your `.text` element : you are containing the max height of your element, but your text need more space when screen is smaller.

So you can remove this style property, or use @media queries to change css behavior for smaller devices like :

```
@media (max-width:576px) {
    .text {
        max-height: inherit;
    }
}
```

```js
(function () {
    var elements;
    var windowHeight;

    function init() {
        elements = document.querySelectorAll(".custom-heading");
        windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    }

    function checkPosition() {
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            var element = elements[i];
            var positionFromTop = elements[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;

            if (positionFromTop - windowHeight <= 0) {
                element.classList.add("ch-animate");
            }
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener("scroll", checkPosition);
    window.addEventListener("resize", init);

    init();
    checkPosition();
})();
```

```css
.custom-heading {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100% !important;
    width: 300px;
}

.custom-heading .text {
    line-height: 1.5em;
    padding-left: 2rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.bh-line,
.vl-line {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background-color: #d70522;
    transition: all 3s ease;
}

.bh-line {
    left: 0;
    bottom: 15%;
    height: 3px;
    width: 0%;
}

.vl-line {
    left: 1rem;
    bottom: -0.3rem;
    height: 0;
    width: 3px;
}

.custom-heading.ch-animate .bh-line {
    width: 100%;
}

.custom-heading.ch-animate .vl-line {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-heading">
    <span class="vl-line"></span>
    <h1 class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h1>
    <span class="bh-line"></span>
</div>
```